# Wrong time format returned by get-counter/export-counter in Powershell

Tags: date, powershell, time, format, powershell-cmdlet

The get-counter/export-counter cmdlets in powershell seem to return dates in the US format which is rather undesirable in this case. I went through both get-help -full pages and couldn't find anything that allows me to set the date/time format. Is there another way to do this that I am not aware of, or am I stuck with the US date format?

Comment: Works for me, actually: http://hypftier.de/dump/SO6433025/counters.png. No braindead date format anywhere and that's vanilla `Get-Counter` output.

Comment: My ultimate purpose is to export the counter to an external file. get-counter does indeed give me the desirable date format, but when exported to csv, it gives the wrong date format (if you view the csv file with Notepad). I should have explained this in my original post, my fault.

Comment: Ran into the same problem with PS3.0 preview 2, decided to just use get-time to a different var and use that, anoying though.

Answer (score 4):

It works so because the culture of your host is "en-US" have a look to :

```
Get-Culture | Format-List *
```

You can change the culture during a Scriptblock execution look at this code

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture = "en-US"
$a = { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
       [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
       get-counter -Counter "\Processeur(_Total)\% temps processeur" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3
     }
&$a

[System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture = "fr-FR"
$a = { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
       [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
       get-counter -Counter "\Processeur(_Total)\% temps processeur" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3
     }

&$a
```

There are a lots of information about that in [Powershell-cookbook](http://www.pavleck.net/powershell-cookbook/ch13.html)

Comment: My culture is set to en-NZ by default and running Get-Date returns the correct format (dd/MM/yyyy). Your example helps with get-counter but not export-counter. It's almost as if it's not culturally sensitive at all. Here is the content of the result csv file, note the date is in MM/dd/yyyy format, which is not what I want. This is really frustrating. How can microsoft have screwed this up?

"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (New Zealand Standard Time)(-720)","\\hostname\physicaldisk(_total)\disk reads/sec"
"06/27/2011 15:03:34.102"," "
"06/27/2011 15:03:36.111","0"
"06/27/2011 15:03:38.123","0"

Comment: You are rigt, something is wrong there. I don't understant why culture apply to Get-counter and not export-counter.

Comment: Done. https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/677402/export-counter-cmdlet-exports-date-in-wrong-timestamp-format-when-written-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 3):

You can always re-format the output:

```
get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3 | 
select @{l="Timestamp";e={([datetime]"$($_.timestamp)").tostring("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")}},Readings | fl





Timestamp : 2011/06/21 18:33:09
Readings  : \\TMA-1\processor(_total)\% processor time :
            3.87658516403437



Timestamp : 2011/06/21 18:33:11
Readings  : \\TMA-1\processor(_total)\% processor time :
            1.93861060616496



Timestamp : 2011/06/21 18:33:13
Readings  : \\TMA-1\processor(_total)\% processor time :
            3.10139633471207
```